# iPhone app take a lot of memory while appending images and loading in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, image, memory, uiwebview, crash

I want to show a tiff file lets say of 25 pages. I have to show tiff file page by page by scrolling. FYI, i don't want to use NSTiffSplitter from github,i want to download next page as user scrolls downward of uiwebview's scrollview.
I am downloading 1st page bytes(array), convert it into .jpeg file(image1.jpeg) and write it into document directory and load this downloaded page into UIWebview. Now when user swipes downward at the end of scrollview, i download the second page of tiff file as bytes,convert it into .jpeg(image2.jpeg), save it into document directory and append it with first page(image1.jpeg), and then load appended image to UIWebview.

This goes fine for lets say 7 pages, on 8 to 10 app shows memory warning and crashes. Let me post the code as well.

My idea is that imageByCombiningImage is eating memory and not releasing it. Needs experts advise.

```
-(void)saveAndDisplayFullImageiPad:(NSDictionary *)dicIn{
    int pageNumber = [[dicIn objectForKey:@"SortNo"]intValue];//page number comes in web service response
    self.currentFilePageCount = [[dicIn objectForKey:@"PagesCount"]intValue];
    NSArray *arrayOfBytes = [dicIn objectForKey:@"FileBytes"];
    if (arrayOfBytes != nil && [arrayOfBytes count] > 0) {

    unsigned c = arrayOfBytes.count;
    uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++){
        NSString *str = [arrayOfBytes objectAtIndex:i];
        int byte = [str intValue];
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
    }
    NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:sizeof(unsigned char)*c];
    free(bytes);

    NSString *fileNameCPath=[dicIn objectForKey:@"FilePath"];
    NSString *fileNamePlusExtension = [[fileNameCPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"] lastObject];
    NSString *justFileName = [[fileNamePlusExtension componentsSeparatedByString:@"." ]firstObject];

    self.standardTiffPageName = [justFileName stringByAppendingString:@"PageNumber"];

    NSString *fileWithPageNum = [justFileName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PageNumber%d.jpeg",pageNumber]];
    NSString *fileWithDirPath = [[[AppSettings sharedAppSettings]getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileWithPageNum];//document directory path appended
    NSLog(@"filePathWritten = %@",fileWithDirPath);
    [data writeToFile:fileWithDirPath atomically:YES];

    self.tiffMainPageName = fileWithDirPath;

    [self.tiffPagesNameArray addObject:fileWithDirPath];//just saving pages path names

    if (pageNumber == 1) {
        self.tiffMainPageName = fileWithDirPath;//tiffMainPageName has the appended images
    }
    if (pageNumber > 1) {

        UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.tiffMainPageName];
        UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileWithDirPath];
        UIImage *finalImage = [self imageByCombiningImage:img1 withImage:img2];
        NSData *dataFinalImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 0.5);
        [dataFinalImage writeToFile:self.tiffMainPageName atomically:YES];
    }

}
[self.webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.tiffMainPageName]]];
self.tiffPageDownloadComplete = YES;
}

- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)image1 withImage:(UIImage*)image2 {

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return finalImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just creating an image that, eventually, is way too big to fit into the memory. Rather then creating a bigger and bigger image by appending previous page's image, may be you could just display the next page's image underneath the previous one.

for webview, you could always generate a new "html page" that would contain your required images. using function like this one:

```
- (NSString*)htmlStringWithImagesOnPaths:(NSArray*)imagePaths {
    NSString* html = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body>";

    for(NSString* imagePath in imagePaths)
        html = [html stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\">", imagePath]];

    return [html stringByAppendingString:@"</body></html>"];
}
```

and then instead of `[self.webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.tiffMainPageName]]]` you would do:

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[webView loadHTMLString:[self htmlStringWithImagesOnPaths:self.imagePaths] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectoryPath]];
```

in this case, you should provide an array of relative paths in the `imagePaths` parameter of the `htmlStringWithImagesOnPaths:` method (relative to the documents directory).

one more note - I'm not sure why after `NSArray *arrayOfBytes = [dicIn objectForKey:@"FileBytes"];` you're converting this byte array to `NSString` and then back to bytes, and then saving it to a file. why not rather save it to a file right away (using `[arrayOfBytes writeToFile:fileWithDirPath atomically:YES])`?

good luck

Comment: web view shows question marks, instead of images. Not working for me.I'm trying to show images from document directory and not from bundle. why the base url is make with empty string.[webView loadHTMLString:[self htmlStringWithImagesOnPaths:self.imagePaths] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]; thanks for your help

Comment: @user1994956 well, it should work even for images that are stored in documents directory. So probably the image urls are not correct. the baseURL should have no effect, if you're using absolute URLs, so I just put an empty string there (can be nil though)... may be easier way how to achieve this actually would be using relative URLs for images and setting the baseURL - I'll edit my post.

Comment: @user1994956 any news? is your application still crashing even when using the technique described? please mark the post as answer if it answers your question. thanks.